# How do I skip the first line if its a 0 or empty

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
get-childitem -path $csvfolder *.inv | get-content | add-content $outputfile
```

I want to skip the first line of the inv file if it's a 0 but if there is only 1 line then I want to copy it.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for based on testing.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -path $csvfolder *.inv | Select -Expand Fullname | ForEach-Object{
    $singleFile = @(Get-Content $_)
    If($singleFile[0] -eq "0" -and $singleFile.Count -gt 1){
        $singleFile | Select-Object -Skip 1
    } Else {
        $singleFile
    }
} | add-content $outputfile
```

In the event a `$singleFile`s first line is `0` and the file has more than one line then the 0 is skipped. I feel that you might be looking for lines that have a 0 in them but you will be able to tell me if this works for you or not. Else the file is just sent down the pipe as normal.